# Plot Dataset items

Tags: plotting, dataset

Assume, I have a `Dataset` like this

```
ds = Dataset[<|
   "Alice" -> <|"food" -> {"apple", "orange"}, 
     "drink" -> {"water", "tea"}|>,
   "Bob" -> <|"food" -> {"apple", "banana"}, 
     "drink" -> {"tea", "coffee"}|> ,
   "Eve" -> <|"drink" -> {"tea"}|>|>]
```

[image]

This data set consists of three individuals and each has observations for food and drink they consume.

I now want to, for example, plot the percentage of tea drinkers (100%), or the percentage (or number) of banana eaters (33%, 1 out of 3).
Ideally this would be a `BarChart like this

[image]

where the first three a, b, c's would be apples, bananas, or oranges.
The second group of a, b, c would be food items.

Please note that there can be missings (e.g. Eve doesn't have food items but she counts towards the three persons)

I tried something like

```
ds[BarChart, {All, All, "food"}]
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: `ds[BarChart[#, ChartLabels -> Automatic] &@*Map[Total]@*Transpose@*
  DeleteMissing@*Map[Counts], "food"]` and `ds[BarChart[#, ChartLabels -> Automatic] &@*Map[Total]@*Transpose@*
  DeleteMissing@*Map[Counts], "drink"]`?

Comment: @kglr thanks, that's pretty close to what I want. How can I get percentages instead of counts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ds2 = ds[Map[Merge[100 Total[#]/Length[ds] &] @* Values @* DeleteMissing] @*
   Transpose @* Map[Map[Counts]], {"food", "drink"}]
```

[image]

```
BarChart[Map[KeyValueMap[Labeled[#2, #] &]] @ #, 
   ChartLabels -> {Callout[Automatic], Automatic}] & @ ds2
```

[image]

Alternatively,

```
operator = BarChart[#, ChartLabels -> {Callout[Automatic], Automatic}] & @*
   Map[KeyValueMap[Labeled[#2, #] &] @*
       Merge[100 Total[#]/Length[ds] &] @*
       Values @* 
       DeleteMissing] @*
   Transpose @* 
   Map[Map[Counts]];

ds[operator, {"food", "drink"}]
```

[image]

```
op = Map[BarChart[#,  ChartLabels -> Automatic] & @* 
         Merge[100 Total[#] / Length[ds] &] @* 
         Values @*
         DeleteMissing] @* 
         Transpose @* 
         Map[Map[Counts]];

ds3 = ds[op]
```

[image]

```
ds3["food"]
```

[image]

```
ds3[Row[{Show[#"food", PlotLabel -> "food", ImageSize -> 300], 
    Show[#"drink", PlotLabel -> "drink", ImageSize -> 300]}] &]
```

[image]